# Way to frame an update query with parameters

Tags: javascript, sqlite, insert, titanium

I am working on an application in Appcelerator Titanium. The application uses sqlite database. For **inserting into the database**, I have written a **query with parameters** like this:

```
db.execute("INSERT INTO formData (unique_id,form_xml_id,dateTime_stamp,data,user_id,status) VALUES ('" + Ti.App.mydata._guid + "'," + findex + ",'"+datetime+"','"+fdata1+"'," + Ti.App.information.user_id + ",'" + formstatus + "')");
```

I have another **query to update** the database for a different table. But the query is without parameters. Like this:

```
db.execute("UPDATE formData SET  form_xml_id=" + findex + ",dateTime_stamp='" + datetime + "',data='" + fdata + "',user_id=" + Ti.App.information.user_id + ",status='"+ DataStatus +"' where unique_id='" + Ti.App.mydata._guid + "'");
```

I want to **rewrite the update query, like the insert query**. How can I do that?

Comment: What do mean by "with/without parameters?" Both queries seem to contain String parameters.

Comment: yes but for the insert one, column names come first then the parameters. In the case of update it is different

Comment: That's just the format of [UPDATE statements in SQL](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a code which update Contacts... you can modify it accordingly:

```
public int updateContact(Contact contact) {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, contact.getName());
        values.put(KEY_PH_NO, contact.getPhoneNumber());

        // updating row
        return db.update(TABLE_CONTACTS, values, KEY_ID + " = ?",
                new String[] { String.valueOf(contact.getID()) });
    }
```

Comment: sorry mine is in javascript, not java

Comment: Ok... you had mentioned Android tag so got me confused